# what is the real use of __return_empty_array in wordpress and when should we use it?

Tags: wordpress

As I have started learning wordpress plugin developement recently but i can't understand the function  __return_empty_array. It returns an array but when should we really use it.

Answer (score 1):

`__return_empty_array` returns an empty array. It is ued to return empty array to filters. For example consider the case of turning off the link of the authors page. You can add the following code to `functions.php` to get it done.

```
add_filter ('author_rewrite_rules', '__return_empty_array');
```

In this case an empty array is returned and `__return_empty_array` is used for it. Hope you get me.